# C# WPF (.Net Core 5) application using a .Net Core 5 DLL that needs user input from a console or a form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms, dll

**General Description**

I am currently developing a complex WPF application (.Net core 5) that uses a .Net core 5 dll which does some work that requires some sort of credentials from the users. Currently, the dll takes those credentials from a config file, but I want the user to have the possibility to input their credentials directly.
The form or the command line in which the users have to input their credentials must be inside the dll and not in the WPF application, because I want the WPF application to be completely loose from the implementation of the dll.

**What I have tried?**

1. I have tried to create a form to be called from the dll, so when the dll needs the credentials, the form will pop up and the user will input their credentials. This did not worked - I received the following error : *Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'*
2. I tried to prompt a console for the user to input their credentials, but this did not worked because the dll is not a console application, neither the WPF application is.

Code example for how I tried to prompt the console for the user to input their credentials:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = "/c" + "set /p dummy= && echo %dummy%",
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = false
                    };
using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please present your OTConnect credentials as follows: -example...");
                        process.WaitForExit();
                        output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    }
```

This did not work because I want the users to be able to see a message in the console in order to know what and how to input their credentials. Either that, or the console will close before the user could input anything.

**What I actually need**

I need some sort of solution **to be able to request the credentials** from the user **directly from the DLL** in some sort of **GUI'ish** way. **The solution should be easy to integrate along with the dll back into the main WPF application**.

Comment: Why you can't have a WPF form that's still in the dll?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I haven't tried that, but can you build a wpf form in a .Net core 5 dll?

Comment: You should not mix the presentation (ui) layer and the logic layer (dll). you could add a delegate to your logic layer with the credential as return value how you get the credential is part of the calling side.

Comment: @Leppin - Could you, please explain in more detail how can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: @GeluPopa I wrote you a small example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rVhJoB

Comment: The error when calling a form makes little sense to me. A .Net 5 application should have no problem calling a .Net 5 dll, so I suspect something odd is going on. That said, I think it is a poor idea since it makes the library much more difficult to test and debug, introduces dependencies, and needs a bit of care to ensure the windowing system is initialized correctly. At minimum you should have some abstraction for providing credentials. So the caller can chose to provide values, show a dialog, or something else depending on the situation.